# Get Process Modules on Process Start-up

Tags: c#, process

I am attempting to get the Process Modules for the game Counter-Strike: Global Offensive.

I can get the modules "client.dll" and "engine.dll" when the game is already running, however I want to get these modules when I start the game.

I have implemented this code to do this:

```
private void WaitForProcess()
{
    startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
    startWatch.EventArrived += startWatch_EventArrived;
    startWatch.Start();
}

private void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);

    if (e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString().Contains("csgo"))
    {
        OpenProcess();
    }
}
```

The code above gets the game process when it is started in the background whilst my program is running, and it executes the code below to get the modules:

```
private ProcessModuleCollection modules;
private Process gameProcess;

private bool OpenProcess()
{
    try
     {
        gameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo").First();
    }
    catch
    {
        WaitForProcess();
    }

    if (gameProcess is null)
        return false;

    while (clientModule == null || engineModule == null)
    {
        modules = gameProcess.Modules;

        foreach (ProcessModule module in modules)
        {
            switch (module.ModuleName.ToLower())
            {
                case "client.dll":
                    clientModule = module;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Client found");
                    break;
                case "engine.dll":
                    engineModule = module;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Engine found");
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Irrelevant module");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

After all of this, I get stuck in the while loop because it cannot find "client.dll" but it can find "engine.dll".

However, when the game is already running, the OpenProcess method encounters no errors and gets both "client.dll" and "engine.dll" fine - the issue only happens when trying to catch the game process starting up.

Comment: Don't use such code to begin with. You got all modules once, no need to keep retrieving them or lowercasing their names. Use a simple loop and check if the module name is one of the names you want instead of repeating the loop for every name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for pointing that out, I'm now using storing `gameProcess.Modules` as a `ProcessModuleCollection`. Still cannot figure out why "client.dll" is not showing as a module though.

Comment: Because it's not loaded? DLLs can be loaded dynamically when needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In that case, shouldn't I keep updating the module list until it's loaded? Considering the DLL is detected without fail when I run the program when the game is already running.